# JAVA - how to set the same field of different classes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a few model classes and these classes has two fields that are the same: approved and checked, both are set to false. I want to create one endpoint to set this fields to true no matter which type of obcject it is. For example two model classes:

```
public class Meal extends Request {

private String id;
private Integer calories;
private LocalDateTime mealTime;
private Double fat;
private Double protein;
private Double carbon;
private Integer weight;
private List<MealElement> mealElements;
private MealStatus mealStatus;
private MealKind mealKind;
private List<Recipe> recipes;
private Boolean approved;
private Boolean checked;

public class Training extends Request {

private String id;
private String trainingName;
private Integer predictedCaloriesToBurn;
private Integer burnedCalories;
private LocalDateTime startTime;
private LocalDateTime endTime;
private List<Exercise> exerciseList;
private List<TrainingLabels> trainingLabels;
private Boolean approved;
private Boolean checked;
private ActivityDay activityDay;
```

I'm creating this using AWS so I have to create lambda to make endpoint for this. Can someone help me with idea how to do it?

Comment: Is there a reason you use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`? The wrapper classes are less efficient and use way more space than the primitive types.

Comment: I thought that to do this task I need to have an object of Boolean type.

Comment: You only need `Boolean` instead of `boolean` if you want to store 3 values: `true`, `false` and `null`. Which you shouldn't do if you don't need to. `Boolean` is, as said, way slower than `boolean` since it's an object and not a primitive data type.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to use one or two interfaces, as follow

```
public interface Checkable {
   setCheck(boolean ckeck);
} 

public interface Approvable {
   setApproved(boolean approved);
}

public class Meal extends Request implements Checkable, Approvable {
   ...
}

public class OtherClass implements Checkable, Approvable {
}



...



// And where you need to use it

public void setChecked(Checkable checkable, boolean value) {
   checkable.setCheck(value);
}

// Calling it as follow
Meal meal = ...
setChecked(meal, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an interface could help?

```
public interface IdSupport {
    public void setId(String id);
    public String getId();
}

public class Meal extends Request implements IdSupport {
   ... 
}
public class Training extends Request implements IdSupport {
   ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Inheritance

The common class should offer an interface for that. Like offering two setter methods. It should also contain the fields as they are part of the common class and not specific to the subclasses.

```
public class Request {
    private boolean approved;
    private boolean checked;

    public void setApproved(boolean approved) {
        this.approved = approved;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
    }

    public boolean isApproved() {
        return approved;
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }
}
```

Your *endpoint* can then just do:

```
someRequest.setApproved(true);
someRequest.setChecked(true);
```

And it will work for every class that is of type `Request`, including your subclasses `Meal` and `Training`.

---

### Interfaces

Even better would be if you move that to an interface like `InspectionItem`:

```
public interface InspectionItem {
    void approve();
    void check();
    boolean isApproved();
    boolean isChecked();
}
```

And then you let the common class implement that:

```
public class Request implements InspectionItem {
    private boolean approved;
    private boolean checked;

    @Override
    public void approve() {
        approved = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void check() {
        checked = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isApproved() {
        return approved;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }
}
```

Then your *endpoint* works on everything which is of type `InspectionItem`, not only `Request`s:

```
someItem.approve();
someItem.check();
```